# Android notifyDataSetChanged not working

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have an adapter which fills a ListView with 2 TextViews with data from a TreeMap.
When the user adds or deletes Data from the ListView, the View should be refreshed.

So here is **my Adapter:**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private final ArrayList mData;

    public MyAdapter(Map<String, String> map) {
        mData = new ArrayList();
        mData.addAll(map.entrySet());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Map.Entry<String, String> getItem(int position) {
        return (Map.Entry) mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO implement you own logic with ID
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_adapter_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            result = convertView;
        }
    Map.Entry<String, String> item = getItem(position);

    // TODO replace findViewById by ViewHolder
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(item.getKey());
    ((TextView) result.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).setText(item.getValue());

    return result;
}}
```

Because I want to update the view from a dialog and on another question I read, that `notifyDataSetChanged()` needs to be called from the UIThread I put my `notifyDataSetChanged()` into a **Runnable. here is it:**

```
Runnable run = new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            Log.v("in the Runnable: ", String.valueOf(colorHashMap));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
```

And this it how the Runnable gets called in the Dialog:

```
DefaultColorActivity.this.runOnUiThread(run);
```

But I no matter what I try or do, the List just won't get updated. I need to close and reopen the activity to get the new List.

Comment: where is your adding and deleting data from listview code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a method in your `adapter` like:

```
 public void updateList(){
   notifyDataSetChanged() 
 }
```

*and call this method when you want to refresh the list*

Answer (score 0):

Call notifyDataSetChanged() method from your Adapter class (in getView() method) which extends BaseAdapter after deleting item.

Comment: could you provide a short example, where to add what?

Comment: see this example this is what you what http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/09/android-listview-notifydatasetchange.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to make changes in map  (Data source of the adapter). And use Handler class(Android OS Thread) to run the thread like this

```
    Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.post(run);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not create object of list.

just create reference and asign list to your list

remove this statement in you adapter class

mData = new ArrayList();